# Dynamically change the visibility of a QLabel and QPushButton when a specific action is triggered

Tags: pyqt5

I'm trying to change QLabel and QPushButton visibility when QLineEdit has one index or more,
so I don't know what the conditionin of the if statment and how to make the QLabel and QPushButton appears dynamically without emits an action,

the code :

```
    import PyQt5
    import sys 
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
    from PyQt5 import QtCore , QtGui , uic
    from PyQt5.QtGui import *
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation , Qt 
    
    
    class Ui(QWidget):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Ui , self).__init__()
    
            uic.loadUi("login_page.ui" , self)
            
            self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
            self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
            self.show()
            
            
            self.on_Run()
    
    
            
            
        
        
        
        def on_Run(self):
            
            self.label.setVisible(False)
            self.Hide_Show_Password.setVisible(False)
    
    
        
        def show_hide_pass(self):
            #Below Code For Hide and Show the password
    
             if self.Password.text() == :
                self.label.setVisible(True)
                self.Hide_Show_Password.setVisible(True)
```

Comment: You should read more about [signals and slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/signalsandslots.html), their implementation in [PyQt](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html) and understand how event loop programming works: there's no point in checking the value of the line edit in the `__init__`, because at that point the user has not typed anything; actually, at that point, the UI has not been even shown yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example below I create a generic button, label, and line edit, and add them to a layout.  Then I connect the `QLineEdit.textChanged` signal to your `show_hide_pass` method which sends the text contents of the widget each time the contents are edited.

I am not 100% sure if you were saying that you only wanted the widgets to be visible if there was at least 1 digit, or if the number 1 appeared in the line edit, so I just chose the former, and am checking the length of the text parameter in the `if` statement, but if you are wanting to check for the number one you can just change that line to `if "1" in text:`. instead.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Ui(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui , self).__init__()
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        # Add Layout and Widgets
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = QLabel("Label")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.Password = QLineEdit()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.Password)
        self.Hide_Show_Password = QPushButton("HideShowPasswordButton")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.Hide_Show_Password)

        # Connect widget signals to they slot methds
        self.Password.textChanged.connect(self.show_hide_pass)
        self.on_Run()

    def on_Run(self):
        self.label.setVisible(False)
        self.Hide_Show_Password.setVisible(False)

    def show_hide_pass(self, text):
         if len(text) > 0:
            self.label.setVisible(True)
            self.Hide_Show_Password.setVisible(True)


app = QApplication([])
window = Ui()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score -1):

@musicamente rightly pointed out that `loadUI` will automatically hook up widget signals to your code. For PyQt5 to find your methods, you must use this naming scheme:

```
def on_<widget_name>_<signal_name>():
```

For a QLineEdit, you will often use the [`returnPressed`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#returnPressed) signal that fires when user presses Return or Enter key. I don't remember if this signal fires when user presses Tab. Assuming your widget is named `lineEdit`, you can add this method to your UI class:

```
def on_lineEdit_returnPressed(self):
    if self.lineEdit.text() == '1':
        self.label.setVisible(True)
        self.Hide_Show_Password.setVisible(True)
```

Comment: No. `uic.loadUi()` already does *everything* `setupUi()` would do with a pyuic form class, including calling `QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName()`; it also does *not* create any `setupUi` member for the instance, so `self.setupUi(self)` should *not* be called anyway.

Comment: @musicamente. You're right: `loadUi` does not need for `setupUi` to be called. I've been using `loadUiType` for years and that does require `setupUi` to be called. I think I prefer to use `loadUi` and will change many of my old apps.

Comment: While both `loadUi` and `loadUiType` can provide same results (in terms of UI creation, translation and possible automatical slot connection), they have slightly different behaviors on the programming level and in terms of performance: the former just does the above on the target (or newly created) widget "on call" (when **each** instance is created), while the latter actually creates a *type* (as the name suggests), which *does* create the `setupUi` member, because it fundamentally creates a form class that would exactly be the same as importing a pyuic generated class from the same ui file.

Comment: They have different benefits, so it's a matter of choice and needs. Both `loadUi` and `loadUiType` explicitly load, parse and process an UI file every time they're called: if you need multiple instances of a target widget (and, possibly, very frequently in a short time interval), `loadUiType` is much faster because both file IO and processing (XML parsing) only happen once; it also allows optional operations on the form class, like further subclassing or online translation. OTOH, `loadUi` is normally written within the class block, so it's easier to refer/recall it when reviewing or debugging.